# How to extract part of a url and populate in an img's src

Tags: jquery, regex, youtube-api

I wanted to get some help on this. I need to take the link that is being pulled in from a feed and extract a portion of the url and then populate it in an img tags src.

```
html += '<'+ options.titletag +' class="rssRow '+row+'"><a href="'+ entry.link +'" title="View this feed at '+ feeds.title +'">'+ entry.title +'</a></'+ options.titletag +'>'
        if (options.date) html += '<div>'+ pubDate +'</div>'
```

So what I am looking to do here is grab the url generated from here + entry.link + and then from the generated link `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acvh0CcSr8k&amp;feature=youtube_gdata` just grab the video ID acvh0CcSr8k

and push that into the img's source

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/**""**/2.jpg" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract the Id (I don't know why the API doesn't provide it though...)

```
/^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(.*?)&/
```

Your id will be in `$1`.

Comment: Yeah the API should have the thumbnail option... So how can I store that so that I can just call that var within the img src

Comment: @Matthew You could just build the image like `$('<img />', { src: 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + id + '/2.jpg', alt: 'YouTube' })`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you're referencing the link, but once you have it, you could try something like this:

```
  // or whatever selector
var link = $('a')[0];

var str = link.search.split('=')[1].split('&')[0];

   // create the image
var $img = $('<img>',{src: "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + str + "/2.jpg"} );
```

or instead of using `.split()`, you could `.slice()` the string, using `.indexOf()`.

```
var str = link.search;
str = str.slice( str.indexOf('=') + 1, str.indexOf('&') );
```

or if you meant that the link is already a string, then you could start by splitting on the `?`.

```
var str = entry.link.split('?')[1];
```

Then continue with the rest above.

Comment: I *think* those `**` were used by him to make it bold, they shouldn't be part of the actual string.

Comment: @alex - Yes, very likely. Removed. :o)